# ¿Por qué no me muestra la carpeta del proyecto en vs code?

Tags: vscode

Ya sea que abra la carpeta con clic derecho, arrastre la carpeta o abra la carpeta desde el vs code en el explorador no me muestra, alguien me podría ayudar.

¡Ya desactivé extensiones y no resolvió!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrarnos un ejemplo de tu problema?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.